# How can I check if a Windows device driver is loaded using Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, driver

I was wondering how I could check if a device driver is loaded using Perl? The operating system is Windows Server 2003, and I'm interested in seeing if the driver for a particular video card is loaded correctly or not.

Comment: Please provide more context, for example, what operating system are you talking about ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way, lookup required Win32 API calls on MSDN, then use Win32::API,
or use sysinternals program  Listdlls.exe

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx#ListDLLs v2.25